# School Start Date DS 160

Tags: usa, f1-visas

In the current education section of the form, it asks what my school start date was. Though my high school start date was 2015, I have been studying in the same school since 12 years. Which date do I put in?

Also, in the previous education background, it asks me to list all the schools I have attended excluding primary school. Since my school is the same, do I put in that I started studying in this school since 2007 even though I was in primary school at the time?

Comment: It looks as though your school start date was 2007. If you attended any other schools between primary school and 2007 you should list them.

Comment: My primary School start date was 2007. I began middle School in 2013 and high school in 2015. The thing is that my high school, middle School, and primary School are the same

Comment: Why don't you just keep it simple and say you were at the school since 2007, which is true, and you attended no other schools, also true, so the matter of primary schools doesn't come into it, since it relates to the "previous schools".

Comment: Because it says to exclude primary school, I would follow those instructions and list the start date for 6th (or 7th) grade. Don't confuse them by listing the elementary school start date even though it was the same school.